# w2ui grid inline edit (date range validations)

Tags: grid, inline, edit, w2ui

Can anyone suggest how to put date range validations in w2ui grid inline edit (Calendar should  display date after start date)

Any hint or suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use following code to put date range validations in w2ui grid inline edit

```
onDblClick: function (event) {
    var editable = w2ui['grid'].columns[event.column].editable
            if (editable !== undefined) {  
                        w2ui['grid'].columns[event.column].editable = { type: 'date',  start: startdate   }; 
                        w2ui['grid'].refresh();
                                         }                            
                            
                        }
```

here startdate is date from where you want to set your calender